# Errors when trying to install PIL with pip as well as pyscripter errors

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, pyscripter

I have installed pip and got a correctly functioning virtual environment (I think). I am trying to now install PIL. When I try and install it, this is the error:

```
C:\Users\CharlesP>python -m pip install python-imaging
Downloading/unpacking python-imaging
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-imaging
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for python-imaging
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\CharlesP\pip\pip.log
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I have also installed pillow, and it says it was installed properly, but I get an error when trying to use the pillow module in PyScripter for the latest version it says that there is no such module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

However, you may consider using Pillow instead, this shouldn't create these kind of problems:

[link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/)

Comment: I'm now getting an error which says there is invalid syntax within the installation?

Answer (score 1):

`python-imaging` is the name that some Linux distros give to the RPM/DEB/etc. package for PIL (the "Python Imaging Library"). There's no such package on PyPI.

[`PIL`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL/1.1.6) itself exists, but it often can't be cleanly installed. It's basically an abandoned project, and you almost certainly don't want it.

What you want is the modern fork [`Pillow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow). One of the many enhancements made over the years is working properly with `pip`. So:

```
pip install pillow
```

If for some reason you can't use Pillow (and I can't think of any good reason, except for needing to work with ancient versions of Python, which don't support `pip`…), you can [download the source to PIL 1.1.7](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and install it manually, or use one of the various "pipify"-ing wrappers (search PyPI for `PIL` and you'll find two or three of them) that may or may not work.

Comment: So, if pyscripter isn't recognising the pillow module (Which I've already installed), what course of action should I take? Is there any way it's looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @Charles: That sounds like a separate problem. I don't know how you're "trying to use the pillow module", but if you're doing something like `import pillow`, that's the problem. You want `import PIL` or `from PIL import Image` or the like—just like with `PIL` (well, just like _one_ way of installing `PIL`; the other way would just give you top-level modules like `Image` instead…).

Comment: @Charles: Also, we'd need to know more about your PyScripter setup, whether you have two or more versions of Python installed, etc., so if you create a new question, please include all of that information.

Comment: @Charles: If you get stuck on something, just post a new question. Even if I don't answer it, someone else probably will; good questions usually get good answers here.